# how to remove distorted widgets in android?

Tags: android, android-widget

i am using samsung galaxy y,in my program there is several activities.in each activity there are many widgets like edittext,button,imagebutton.In all activity there,all the widgets are distorted in my phone.But all are ok with the emulator.How to fix this error.

I noticed one thing that,one of my activity contain widgets inside a scroll view,some widgets are ok in its initial position and some are ok with a particular position while scrolling.

These problems are not affected in my emulator.

one layout example.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right"
>
    <ImageButton android:src="@drawable/btclose"
    android:id="@+id/btclose"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_width="32px"
    android:layout_height="32px"
    >
    </ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <EditText android:id="@+id/txtdisp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:editable="false"

    >

    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="right"
>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btac"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="AC"
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btbak"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="bkspc"
    >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnum7"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="7"
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnum8"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="8"
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnum9"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="9"
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btdiv"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="/"
    >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnum4"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="4"
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnum5"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="5"
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnum6"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="6"
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btmul"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="*"
    >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnum1"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="1"
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnum2"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="2"
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnum3"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="3"
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btsub"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="-"
    >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btpoint"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="."
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnum0"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="0"
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btequel"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="="
    >
    </Button>
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btadd"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="50px"
    android:text="+"
    >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Resolution in the emulator BuiltIn:WVGA800

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please share the xml code for the layouts as well as some screenshots of the activity on the emulator as well as on the device? Please also share the resolution set on the emulator.

Comment: @Soham i just add layout and resolution.i will add pics soon.

Comment: @Soham ,all corners of the edit text as well as text box are distorted.that is the problem

Comment: yup, i think i have a fair idea of the problem, will confirm it after the screenshots

Comment: @Soham.from the second pic we can realize that only three text box is distorted

Answer (score 2):

It took me hours to discover what caused this problem but it is the missing `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="7" />` tag in AndroidManifest.xml that for no normal reason makes Samsung Galaxy Y behave like described in this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try setting the android:layout_height attribute to "wrap_content" or "fill_parent" for all EditTexts and Buttons?

Moreover, the way you are hardcoding the width and height with pixels in not a good practice at all. If you have to set width and height, use [DP/SP which are mentioned here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) Again refrain from hard coding width n height and switch to relative layout which will help buttons and other elements to better align with each other.

Also note that you phone is running at a completely different resolution from that on the android emulator and therefore a lot of the elements are rendered differently. The link above mentions how you can build different layouts and include different drawables to account for the different resolutions and screen densities.

Comment: i tried fill_parent/wrap_content instead of hard cord width and height.The buttons were small according to the text and the distortion is same.i think some other problem